# PHP json_encode not return persian date

Tags: php, json

I want use `json_encode`

This code return correct value :

```
$date = 'امروز'; // return \u0627\u0645\u0631\u0648\u0632
```

But this code not reurn encode :

```
$date = jdate('d F Y',strtotime($row["date"])); // return 02 فروردين 1395
```

How i can solve this problem ?

I want second code return json

> PHP code :

```
$output['dayOne'] = 'امروز';
$output['dayTwo'] = jdate('d F Y',strtotime($row["date"]));;
echo json_encode($output);
```

Export :

```
{"dayOne":"\u0628\u0646\u0632\u06cc\u0646","dayTwo":"07 ارديبهشت 1395"}
```

Comment: this is normal, it's a unicode representation

Comment: @heximal How i can convert to  json ? simple \u0627\u0645\u0631\u0648\u0632

Comment: you don't need to convert it. if your site running on UTF-8 charset, then you just output it to html and the browser will display it normally. if you want to compare it in code you also don't need to convert it, you just make something like `if (date == '02 فروردين 1395') echo("date matches!");`

Comment: In my code if use $date = 'فروردین'; converted to \u0627\u0645\u0631\u0648\u0632. but i use jdate function not convert ! i want convert to \u0627\u0645\u0631\u0648\u0632